# POST Method with JAX-RS does not work correctly with postman tool

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I have been testing my REST Service with the PostMan tool. It works fine when I am trying to hit the `@POST` method with content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and set all the data in body as a `x-www-form-urlencoded` parameters.

But when I changed my service method so that it can accept form param only and then I tried to hit service through postman on setting all the parameter as from-data in request body. I am getting null value in form param in service.

postman attachment:

**Setting form param**
[image: Setting form param]

**Setting Content type**
[image: Setting Content type]

**Service Method**
[image: Service Method]

Comment: did you try to mark 'x-form-urlencoded' in body tab ?

Comment: With 'x-form-urlencoded' I am able to hit the service but problem is all the parameter will be apended as a queryparameter in URL. That's why I want to use form param.

Comment: `form-data` in Postman is for `multipart/form-data`, which is different from `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`